# Informix: count number of columns in a temp table?

Tags: informix

I'm using IDS 11.70.

I want to be able to get the count of the number of columns in a temporary table so in 4gl/genero code I can have a function that puts the right number of question marks into a 'put cursor' statement.

For example, want to replace this sort of code:

```
    declare put_curs1 cursor for
    insert into my_temp_table values(?,?,?,?,?,?)
```

With something like this:

```
let str = "insert into my_temp_table values (
    format_place_holder_string_for_insert( "my_temp_table" ) CLIPPED, ")"
prepare put_stment1 from str
declare put_curs1 cursor for put_stment1
```

We already do this for our regular tables, so if the table schema should be changed to have more or less columns then the code won't break with the wrong number of columns on inserts using put cursors.
In this function for regular tables, to get the column count we use:

```
   select count(*)
    from systables, syscolumns
    where systables.tabname = table_name
    and systables.tabid = syscolumns.tabid
```

But in trying to do it for temporary tables, I can't see what I join to or what column indicates how many columns are in the temporary table. This is what I have so far:

```
select *
FROM sysmaster:systabnames n, sysmaster:systabinfo i, sysmaster:syssessions s 
WHERE sysmaster:bitval(i.ti_flags, "0x0020") = 1 
AND n.dbsname = database_name
AND i.ti_partnum = n.partnum 
AND s.sid = dbinfo("sessionid")
AND n.tabname = table_name;
```

So instead of `select *`  I need `select count( columns )` - but where do I join to so I can count the columns? I poked around but can't find the join I need.

Thanks,
  Bryce Stenberg

Answer (score 1):

The classic way to do it is to prepare 'SELECT * FROM temptable', describe the statement, and get the column count from the description, and then free the prepared statement.  That involves dropping down into ESQL/C, though...or most likely does.

Untested code — with flabby to non-existent error checking:

```
int cols_in_temp_table(int nargs)
{
    $ char buffer[300];
    struct sqlda *u;
    char tabname[129];
    if (nargs != 1)
        ibm_lib4gl_fatalError(...);
    popstring(tabname, sizeof(tabname));
    sprintf(buffer, "SELECT * FROM %s", tabname);
    $ PREPARE p FROM :buffer;
    $ DESCRIBE p INTO u;
    retint(u.sqld);
    $ FREE p;
    free(u);
    return(1);
}
```

Call in I4GL:

```
DEFINE n INTEGER

LET n = cols_in_temp_table("the_temp_table")
```

The code will actually work for any table, temporary or not, so the function name is a slight misnomer.

I can't find anything in the `sysmaster` database that tells you about the columns in a temporary table. That's not quite the same as "there is no such table", but it is fairly close to it.

Comment: Hi Jonathan, in our environment we don't use any ESQL/C so I won't be able to implement your solution. We only use Genero for our coding. The database must know what columns are in the temporary tables somewhere, maybe someone knows where to find it...  Thank you for your reply. Regards, Bryce Stenberg.

Answer (score 1):

I tested the code bellow with success over ifx 11.50 FC9.

`WARNING:` I used an undocumented function. I don't know if is safe use it over production...

How works: I "transform" the row to ROW datatype ; use a internal function called collectionoutput to convert this ROW to lvarchar and then count how much comma have (columns separator).

Pre-req : Permission to create/run the function; the temp table must have 1 line at least.

```
--drop function count_cols;
create function count_cols ( cols lvarchar(4000) ) returning int ;
  define i int;
  define ncols int;
  define isstring int;
  let ncols = 1;
  let isstring = 0;

  for i = 1 to length(cols)
    if substr(cols,i,1) = "'"  and isstring = 1 then
      let isstring = 0 ;
      continue for;
    end if ;
    if substr(cols,i,1) = "'"  and isstring = 0 then
      let isstring = 1 ;
      continue for;
    end if ;
    if isstring = 0 and substr(cols,i,1) = ',' then
       let ncols = ncols+1 ;
    end if ;
  end for ;
  return ncols;
end function
;


--drop table t2;
create temp table t2 ( cod int, desc char(100) default 'test', data datetime year to second default current year to second , number int);
insert into t2 (cod)values (0);
insert into t2 (cod)values (0);
insert into t2 values (1,'teste,teste,teste,teste',current, 0);

select * from t2;
select collectionoutput(multiset(select first 1 * from t2 where cod = 1)) from sysmaster:sysdual ;
select count_cols(collectionoutput(multiset(select first 1 * from t2 where cod = 1))) from sysmaster:sysdual;
```

my outputs (dbaccess)

```
cod     0
desc    test
data    2013-03-22 11:36:37
number

cod     0
desc    test
data    2013-03-22 11:36:37
number

cod     1
desc    teste,teste,teste,teste
data    2013-03-22 11:36:37
number  0

(expression)  MULTISET{ROW(1          ,'teste,teste,teste,teste
                                                                           ','2
              013-03-22 11:36:37',0          )}

(expression)

           4
```

Comment: Hi, sorry it has taken so long to reply.

Comment: Hi, sorry it has taken so long to reply. I tried out your code above and it works. However, when I try to use it with one of our real temp tables created with `select * from myTable into temp TmpMyTable with no log` I get errors of `Error Code: -9930,  Byte, Text, Serial, Serial8 or Bigserial datatypes in collection types not allowed.` We use serial in a lot of tables so it looked promising but not right for my situation. I take it the undocumented function is the 'collectionoutput'?  I may take this question to the IIUG list for more ideas.  Thanks, Bryce.

Answer (score 0):

FYI - If using 12.10 - Could create real instance of your temp table and get columns count from system tables.

1) CREATE TABLE yourtemp_chck SELECT * FROM yourtemp where 1=2;
2) Check sys tables for number of columns
3) Drop yourtemp_chck

Although I've not tried to create a real table from a temp one but does work with real from real for v12.10.

In any version could also just create real table so can get column count from system tables and drop after. I've seen this in really old 4GL. Not something id do unless no other option.

Comment: Thanks for that idea - I'll give it a go when I have time, although currently only running 11.70. I'll comment here again once I have tried.  Cheers, Bryce.